# Как отменить серию коммитов у файла в git?

Tags: git

Допустим, у меня 10-ок коммитов по файлу и в один момент я понимаю, что я хочу откатиться к 5-му коммиту у конкретного файла.

Как это грамотно делается?
Сейчас я в Visual Studio поочередно делаю revert коммитов.

Answer (score 3):

вам понадобится знать хэш коммита

```
$ git checkout <commit_hash> -- <file>
```

Comment: Запушится это все потом без доп. телодвижений?

Comment: сделаете новый коммит и пушните без проблем